# "Content Encoding Error" when refreshing a page with a tracking parameter

Tags: htaccess, url

Our email marketing system tracks clicks by appending a unique string after links within the email i.e. `www.example.com/buy-now?tracking1` & `www.example.com/buy-now?tracking2` etc.

The problem is: if a user views their email in the web browser, clicks on a link and then navigates back (via the browser button) to the email, the link no longer works. Refreshing the web page after the user has clicked through also breaks.

This doesn't show a 404 but a "This site can't be reached" error

This specific email links to multiple websites and there's only one site where this is happening.

Is this something that can be addressed via the .htaccess file?

Comment: Can you give us an example of a real URL that only works the first time?     "This site can't be reached" sounds more like a network error.   I can't imagine that a tracking parameter would cause that.

Comment: I didn't get a network error.   I got the error (in Firefox): "Content Encoding Error -- The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression."

Comment: I also see this comment at the bottom of the page:  `<!-- Dynamic page generated in 1.034 seconds. --> <!-- Cached page generated by WP-Super-Cache on 2017-10-04 10:24:46 --> <!-- Super Cache dynamic page detected but late init not set. See the readme.txt for further details. --> `   That makes me think that this Super Cache plugin is the problem, or at least part of the problem.

Comment: I get an error page even if I switch browsers.   It doesn't appear to be cookie or client related.   It appears that it is getting cached on the server side incorrectly.   More evidence pointing to your cache plugin.

Comment: Chrome does say it is a network error, but the specific reason is `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`.

Comment: Stephen you are my favourite person of the day. Yes it was to do with WP-Super-Cache. Thank you so much for identifying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stephen Ostermiller identified, the issue was caused by a Wordpress caching plugin (WP-Super-Cache)

**To fix the issue:**

Go to Settings > Advanced > Then tick the box saying `Don’t cache pages with GET parameters. (?x=y at the end of a url)`

[image]

Comment: Other forums indicate that you can solve this by either removing the plugin or disabling gzip compression in Apache.   If you could figure out which settings in the cache plugin can be used to avoid this plugin, your post would be a more useful resource than anything else out there on the internet about this.

Comment: Another possibility is to install a different WordPress caching plugin.  I usually install the "W3 Total Cache" plugin in WordPress and I haven't seen his error from it.

Comment: I have experimented and found the specific option for fixing this issue. Answer updated.